# Find best team in array of object with a better complexity

Tags: javascript

I need to return the name of the team that has the biggest points and if there are 2 with same points so return the one that has the best goal average.

**(win = 3pts; lose = 0pt; draws = 1pt)**

Here an exemple:

```
champions([
 {
 name: "Manchester United",
 wins: 30,
 loss: 3,
 draws: 5,
 scored: 88,
 conceded: 20,
 },
 {
 name: "Arsenal",
 wins: 24,
 loss: 6,
 draws: 8,
 scored: 98,
 conceded: 29,
 },
 {
 name: "Chelsea",
 wins: 22,
 loss: 8,
 draws: 8,
 scored: 98,
 conceded: 29,
 },
])
```

**➞ "Manchester United"**

I have the solution but I think that I use too much higher order functions and maybe the complexity of my function is too big .. how can I reduce all of my jumble ?

Here my code:

```js
const champions = (teams) => {
  let idxOfBest = null;
  let points = teams.map(a => (a.wins * 3) + a.draws)
  
  idxOfBest = points.indexOf(Math.max(...points))
  
  let haveSamePoints = points.indexOf(Math.max(...points)) !== points.lastIndexOf(Math.max(...points))

  if (haveSamePoints) {
    let teamsSamePoints = teams.filter(a => (a.wins * 3) + a.draws == (teams[idxOfBest].wins * 3) + teams[idxOfBest].draws)
    let goalDiff = teamsSamePoints.map(a => a.scored - a.conceded)
    let idxOfGoals = goalDiff.indexOf(Math.max(...goalDiff))
    return teamsSamePoints[idxOfGoals].name
  } else {
    return teams[idxOfBest].name
  }
}


console.log(champions([
 {
 name: "Manchester United",
 wins: 30,
 loss: 3,
 draws: 5,
 scored: 88,
 conceded: 20,
 },
 {
 name: "Arsenal",
 wins: 24,
 loss: 6,
 draws: 8,
 scored: 98,
 conceded: 29,
 },
 {
 name: "Chelsea",
 wins: 22,
 loss: 8,
 draws: 8,
 scored: 98,
 conceded: 29,
 },
]))
```

Comment: I edited how to count the points (win, draw, lose)

Comment: A comment in addition to my answer: in terms of style, it's not that you're using too many higher-order functions, it's that you're defining too many variables. FWIW, I always use `const` if possible, `let` only if necessary. As a result I find that my `const`s out-number my `let`s by a very large margin.

Comment: @geofh Thank you A LOT.

Answer (score 3):

You could just sort based on the highest score and goal diff at one go, and get the name of the top ranked.

```js
const champions = (teams) => {

  return [...teams].sort((teamA, teamB) => {
    const pointsA = teamA.wins * 3 + teamA.draws;
    const pointsB = teamB.wins * 3 + teamB.draws;

    if (pointsA != pointsB) {
      return pointsA > pointsB ? -1 : 1;
    }

    const goalsA = teamA.scored - teamA.conceded;
    const goalsB = teamB.scored - teamB.conceded;

    if (goalsA != goalsB) {
      return goalsA > goalsB ? -1 : 1;
    }

    return 0;
  })[0].name;
}


console.log(champions([
  { name: "Manchester United", wins: 30, loss: 3, draws: 5, scored: 88, conceded: 20 },
  { name: "Arsenal", wins: 24, loss: 6, draws: 8, scored: 98, conceded: 29 },
  { name: "Chelsea", wins: 22, loss: 8, draws: 8, scored: 98, conceded: 29 },
]))
```

Comment: Why return [...teams] and not teams itself ?

Comment: @YoëlZerbib the sort method is destructive. `[...teams]` creates a copy so that the original array passed to the function doesn't get modified.

Answer (score 1):

a for loop may be ok.

```js
const points = (team) => {
  // 3 points for win and 1 for draw
  return team.wins * 3 + team.draws;
};

const goalDiff = (team) => {
  return team.scored - team.conceded;
}

const champions = (teams) => {
  let maxPoints = points(teams[0]);
  let maxGoalDiff = goalDiff(teams[0]);
  let idx = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < teams.length; i++) {
    const curPoints = points(teams[i]);
    const currGoalDiff = goalDiff(teams[i]);

    if ((curPoints > maxPoints) ||
      (curPoints === maxPoints && currGoalDiff > maxGoalDiff)) {
      maxPoints = curPoints;
      maxGoalDiff = currGoalDiff;
      idx = i;
    }
  }

    return teams[idx].name;
};
```

Comment: I understood this very quickly, it's concise and helpful thank you.

Comment: you are welcome. it is important to have readable code so that you can come back later to make changes (without having to struggle to understand the logic)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you break this down by writing a function (called say, `rankedHigher`) that takes two teams and returns true if the first team would be ranked higher. That function would encapsulate the tie-break feature. After that it's easy to write the rest; you just set the current leader to the first team, then iterate through the rest and re-assign the leader when a call to `rankedHigher` returns true.

I feel like that will set you on the right path, since your question is not "how do I do it" but "how do I make it more concise".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make your code more readable by using `map`'s second argument:

```
const champion = teams => {
  const scores = teams.map(t => 3 * t.wins + t.draws)
  const maxScore = Math.max(...scores)
  const candidates = teams.filter((_, i) => scores[i] === maxScore)
  if (candidates.length === 1) {
    return candidates[0].name
  }
  else {
    const goalDiffs = candidates.map(t => t.scored - t.conceded)
    const maxGoalDiff = Math.max(...goalDiffs)
    return teams.find((_, i) => goalDiffs[i] === maxGoalDiff).name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this would be to loop over the array and find the best as you go. Sorting is inefficient here as that's a more complicated process than a loop and requires redundant calculations. The difference between this and a sorting type solution would be almost nothing for small arrays, but as you get larger, there's much more of a difference O(n) vs O(nLog(n)) if I'm not mistaken.

```js
const champions = (teams) => {
  let bestScore = 0;
  let bestIdx = 0;
  let bestDiff = -Infinity;
  teams.forEach((team, idx) => {
    const points = team.wins * 3 + team.draws;
    const diff = team.scored - team.conceded;
    if (points > bestScore || points === bestScore && diff > bestDiff) {
      bestScore = points;
      bestIdx = idx;
      bestDiff = diff;
    }
  })
  return teams[bestIdx].name;
}


console.log(champions([{
    name: "Manchester United",
    wins: 30,
    loss: 3,
    draws: 5,
    scored: 88,
    conceded: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "Arsenal",
    wins: 24,
    loss: 6,
    draws: 8,
    scored: 98,
    conceded: 29,
  },
  {
    name: "Chelsea",
    wins: 22,
    loss: 8,
    draws: 8,
    scored: 98,
    conceded: 29,
  },
]))
```